# Hazelcast clients are kept waiting until the IMap finished loading all the elements using the MapLoader's loadAll method

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm using a MapLoader to load items from an Oracle database to a Hazelcast IMap. There are large volumes of data and loading takes a long time. While the map is loading, the consumer applications are kept blocked on GET operations done on the iMap.

Is there any way to avoid keeping the clients waiting until the map finishes loading all the elements?

The Hazelcast server is designed by using a Spring Boot application and having the `com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.1.1` as a dependency.
The clients are also Spring Boot applications using `com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:4.1.1`.

I'm using inside the hz server app a CommandLineRunner at start-up accessing the map: `hazelcastInstance.getMap("my-imap");`

I've tried with both LAZY and EAGER initial-modes but it doesn't help.

Below you can find the config I'm using for the map.

```
in-memory-format: BINARY
metadata-policy: CREATE_ON_UPDATE
statistics-enabled: true
cache-deserialized-values: ALWAYS
backup-count: 0
map-store:
  enabled: true
  initial-mode: EAGER
  class-name: com.example.CustomMapLoader
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/data-structures/working-with-external-data#loading-data-from-your-external-store):

> LAZY - After getting or creating the map, the MapLoader.loadAllKeys() method is triggered when you first access a map using one of the IMap Operations that Trigger MapStore and MapLoader. LAZY is the default mode.

and javadoc of `com.hazelcast.config.MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode#LAZY`:

> Each partition is loaded when it is first touched.

So when you ask for the IMap it loads all *keys* and then when you do `get` on the map it loads its whole partition for that key. It doesn't load all data.

You have two options:

- increase the number of partitions, so it will load a smaller number of items for a single partition, blocking the application for a shorter time
- return `null` from `loadAllKeys` in your MapLoader and either not pre-load data at all (load would be called for specific keys) or load the data separately e.g. from your own thread.

Comment: I thought of a workaround to have besides the original map an additional map with its loader and inside the ```loadAll``` method I could get a reference to the original map (using the hazelcastInstance) and add elements to it using ```putTransient``` method. I'm just curious about the reason for which the framework doesn't offer a feature for this scenario.

Comment: The answer to that is simple - there either wasn't demand or it had less priority than other features. Feel free to create a feature request at github.